# How to fully remove phpMyAdmin?

Tags: server, uninstall, phpmyadmin

I have a server with Ubuntu Server on it. I installed phpMyAdmin but I made a mistake during installation and I need to start over. I need help uninstalling *every single file that came with phpMyAdmin*.

Thanks for the answers, you're very appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the method you used to install it. Did you install a package or just downloaded from web and decompressed into web server (Apache?) directory?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you installed it from the Ubuntu repositories, the command to uninstall it is:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

The `purge` instead of `remove` instructs `apt-get` to remove its configuration files too, including the configuration it added to Apache's configuration directories.

You may be prompted for whether you want to remove its database as well.  This will remove the phpMyAdmin-specific database from your MySQL server.  It won't harm the MySQL server.  In your case, select *Yes*.  If you are not prompted to do this you will need to remove its database manually.

If you installed it manually by extracting files into a web server directory, just delete all those files, and remove its database from your MySQL server assuming you got that far in the installation.

Comment: using this command, system ask you if you would wish to remove the databases as well... be careful to select No

Comment: If you really want to fully remove phpMyAdmin, you probably want to remove its database too. Select Yes.  Note: this removes any phpMyAdmin-specific databases from your MySQL server - it won't harm the MySQL server itself or the data on it.